Как отбирать только последнее вхождение в ретроспективной проверке?
Есть строки вида /text/text/.../text/searchedText/tests/text и в них надо регуляркой найти searchedText. Пробовал выражение типа (?<=/).*?(?=/tests), но оно реагирует на первый же слэш в начале текста. Просьба подсказать, как правильно переписать выражение, чтобы оно отбирало только последнее вхождение / перед вторым условием.

\/([^\/]+)(?=\/tests)

Это должно сработать так как надо
